Render liquid fluid simulation scene with low disk space

I have a fluid simulation with particles enabled
Each frame of fluid simulation takes about 3 GB of disk space at a low domain resolution, with the majority caused by cache_fluid/particles/*.vdb
I have 100 GB of disk space, so I can only simulate ~35 frames before I run out of space
At a 60 FPS rendered video, that is only half a second which is not enough for me

How can I run a longer fluid sim and render with limited disk space?

There is a "is resumable" toggle for fluid sims
Can I bake simulation for frames 1 to 15, render, delete cache, and resume baking on frames 16 to 30, until I am done with the whole simulation (10,000 frames)?

Which cache files can I delete after frame 15 to get more space for frames 16 to 30?
Deleting all cache files makes it impossible to resume
Is there a less tedious way to do this?




i don't know how big your domain is - but it sounds huuuuuge. Maybe you can optimize that?

@Chris it is 2x2x2 (default cube) at 128 domain resolution with spray, foam, and bubble particles. It is the spray, foam, and bubble particles that causes the large sizes (but I want to keep the particles in my renders).
